# Torch7 Access one element from a Tensor as a Tensor

Tags: torch

I'm working on Torch7 to train some neural nets and I've got a Tensor of dim 1 (vector) and I want to access the element i in this vector.
Unfortunately, it gives me an integer instead of a Tensor of size 1.

I got this :

```
matrix = torch.Tensor{1,2}
>  1
   2
  [torch.DoubleTensor of size 2]
matrix[1]
> 1
```

I want this :

```
matrix[1]
> 1 
  [torch.DoubleTensor of size 1]
```

I'm obliged to do this :

```
torch.Tensor{matrix[1]}
> 1 
  [torch.DoubleTensor of size 1]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [torch indexing operator](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/tensor.md#tensor--dim1dim2--or--dim1sdim1e-dim2sdim2e-) as follow:

```
> t = matrix[{ {1} }]
> = t
 1
[torch.DoubleTensor of size 1]
```